# Stop a jQuery content slider when playing a YouTube video

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to create a jQuery content slider that will stop when a YouTube video is played and resume when the video is stopped. Similar to the slider on [taprootfoundation.org](http://www.taprootfoundation.org/).

player.getPlayerState() in the [YouTube JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status) returns the status of the player. A video that has not started should return a value of -1.

My script below uses return false; to stop the slideshow if getPlayerState() returns any value other than -1. Taking the **bottom block in the code below** (followed by //detect playing YouTube video) out, it works fine, but currently the "return false;" is firing regardless of the getPlayerState() value.

I used swfobject to embed the player, as recommended in the YouTube JavaScript API. Here's a [screenshot showing the HTML of the embedded player](http://screencast.com/t/DTeVhRtl28).

I must be calling .getPlayerState() incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//initial setup
    //adds class "last" to last link-tab item
    $('.link-tab:last').addClass('last');

    //moves summary elements down out of view
    $('.rotate-image > div').children('.summary').css({bottom:-150});

//initial variables
    var captionAnimationTime = 300;
    var captionPauseTime = 4800;
    var slideTime = 6000;

//detect playing YouTube video
/*  window.setTimeout(function(){
            video = document.getElementById("boundless-playground-video");
    }
    , captionAnimationTime);
*/
//main function
slideSwitch = function(){
    var $active = $('.rotate-image > div.active');

    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('.rotate-image > div:last');

    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('.rotate-image > div:first');

    //sets indexCurrent variable as the index of the next active banner item in the slideshow
    var indexCurrent = $next.prevAll().length;

    //removes "active" class from link-tab items that already have it
    $('.link-tab.active').removeClass('active');
    //gives class "active" to next link-tab item
    $('.link-tab').eq(indexCurrent).addClass('active');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    //function to slide down the caption
    captionDown = function(){
        $next.children('.summary').animate({bottom:-150}, captionAnimationTime);
    }

    $next.css({opacity:0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 700, function(){
            //remove classes from the previously active item
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');

            //animates slide of summary element
            $next.children('.summary').animate({bottom: 0}, captionAnimationTime);
            window.setTimeout(captionDown, captionPauseTime);
        });

    //detect playing YouTube video - currently stopping regardless of player state
    video = document.getElementById("boundless-playground-video");
    if(video.getPlayerState() != -1){
        return false;
    }
};

//run the function once on document ready to show first slide
slideSwitch();

$(function(){
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", slideTime);
});
```

});

Comment: I think you will need to show the code that controls the slider.  We can advise on the API calls, but do not know how you are implementing your slider exactly.  Unless the code is identical to the link given.

Comment: bind a function that stops the jQuery slider (using whatever method the jQuery slider has, e.g., $('#slider').stop(); ) to the youtube player's "onStateChange" event (see the API).

Comment: updated the question with my code controlling the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it after much pulling of hair. I was having a scope issue when placing the YouTube API call inside the

```
jQuery $(document).ready(function(){
});
```

What I did was place said YouTube API call in the top of the jQuery document.

```
//playerState variable shows status of YouTube video. 
//see http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html
//currently hardcoded with id of video
function onYouTubePlayerReady(){
  ytplayer = document.getElementById('boundless-playground-video');
  ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange','onytplayerStateChange');
}
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
  playerState = newState;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
//insert other stuff here
if (typeof (playerState) == 'undefined'){
window.playerState = 5;
}
alert(window.playerState);
});
```